# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following when creating trigger for autoincrement

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I face that Problem when i creating a trigger.
please see it and give me the solution for help me to solved this problem

that the code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TEST_ID_AUTO 
BEFORE INSERT ON TEST
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SELECT 'E-'||TO_CHAR(NVL(MAX(TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(EMP_ID,3))),100)+1) INTO :NEW.EMP_ID 
FROM TEST
END;
```

Comment: This is the generic message for a **syntax  error or typo**. In this case you're missing the semi-colon after 'from test'.

Comment: Your trigger will not work anyway. You will face an `ORA-04091: table TEST is mutating, trigger/function might not see it`

Comment: Fairly poor design. Better use an integer number for EMP_ID with sequence `CREATE SEQUENCE EMP_ID_SEQ START WITH 100 NOMAXVALUE MINVALUE 100 NOCYCLE;` and `:NEW.EMP_ID := EMP_ID_SEQ.NextVal;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Oracle Database integrated development environment (IDE) can help you.

You can use the SHOW ERRORS command to get more feedback on the problems found in your code at compilation time.

The client-side parser built into Oracle SQL Developer will also remind you as you type when there's something 'amiss' - in this case, the
 END;

in your code confuses the parser because it sees that code as part of your SELECT INTO line above, because you forgot the statement terminator (;)

[image]

Instead of using the SHOW ERRORS command, SQL Developer automatically shows you your compiler feedback - just ensure your View > Log panel is activated.

[image]

If you double-click on the error, it will advance your cursor to the line associated with the error. Your problem should generally be immediately preceding it - in this case, your missing ';) on line 6.